# Build Penetration Testing LAB in VmWare

Tags: web-applications, vmware, penetration-testing

I need to build a Penetration Testing LAB for WEB application by using VmWare Workstation. I need to know how should it be done or how can I do it. Also I need to do the following criteria:
1.  Proposed a General Architecture of Peneteraion  testing Lab
2.  Types of Software that is needed to set up a Penteraion  testing Lab
3.  Different components of Penteraion testing in details
4.  All the configuration and steps to build Penteraion testing Lab

Comment: Try [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) A linux distro with a great number of pre-installed pentest tools.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to set up a penetration lab.
What i did when i started was

- Set up penetration testing linux distribution (In your case it should be kali)
- A Windows Vista machine to attack
- Backups of the vista machine (In case I broke it)
  There is a function in VMWare to do that

You can set up different kinds of machines so if you want to attack a web server and not a machine you can do that. All the configs for the machine you can play around with yourself

This is a broad question so I can only offer personal experience

Answer (score 0):

For learning Web Application Penetration testing you can use vulnerable vm's which can be found in [vulnhub website](https://www.vulnhub.com/)

I highly recommend you to check the above mentioned website where you can download vulnerable vm's and iso images where you can play around. If you are planning to set up complete penetration testing lab covering vulnerable apps and systems this  [best road map](http://www.amanhardikar.com/mindmaps/Practice.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let's call it Web application **CTF**.

Before you start thinking about which server you should run the CTF on, you need to do the following steps:

**1. Chose your CTF level.**
please be noted, that the easiest CTF to build, is the hard one.

**2. Creat Vulnarbilities database** -don't let the level to the CTF affect your database.

**3. Building a machine story**. This is where your CTF level and the
vulnerability database is meet each other.

You can indeed take a normal and easy vulnerability such as XSS and make it completely difficult to find, but you can also take more advanced vulnerability such as XXE and make it simple. So the machine story is the most important part.
In the machine's story part, you also decide if you want to have rabbit holes in your machine.

**4. Chose the application server**

Take into consideration the vulnerabilities database and on which server it will be the best to implement them.

**5. Choosing the OS**

On which OS it will be the easiest to manage your application server and database?

**6. Building the front-end**

you can either choose a website template or you can build one on your own, it does not matter.

**7. Building the back-end**

In this part, you need to pay attention to the tools you use to build it.
Try not to use the newest tools which are more likely to be secure, remember you want your machine to be hackable.

**8. Implement the vulnerabilities**

After you have a full-function website, now is the time to implement all of the vulnerabilities in your databases.

**9. Creat a Write-up**

It is important, better to have one, in any case.

**10. Ask people to solve your CTF while you give them help**

Your mission here is simple. Find out to things:

A. *Does the machine story work as a plan?* ( that's means that they can't skip vulnerabilities in order to solve the machine )

B. *Are they any bugs in the CTF?*

keep in mind that if someone finds a different way to hack your CTF, it's not a bug it's a feature.

Hope this guide will help you, good luck.